# Consume Split Partition List in C#

Tags: c#, arraylist, ienumerable

how can i consume this method of split List<>

```
private List<List<T>> SplitPartition<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, int size)
{
    var chunks = new List<List<T>>();
    var count = 0;
    var temp = new List<T>();

    foreach (var element in collection)
    {
        if (count++ == size)
        {
            chunks.Add(temp);
            temp = new List<T>();
            count = 1;
        }
        temp.Add(element);
    }
    chunks.Add(temp);

    return chunks;
}
```

I wanna implement this list partition to my existing code:

```
public void ExportToCsv()
{
    List<GenerateModel> members = getDataTop5000(); // I got data from my List of Data with return List<>

    int offset = 0;
    const int numberPerBatch = 500000; // count parameter.
    double LoopMax = Math.Ceiling(members.Count / (double)numberPerBatch);

    var PartitionMembers = members.SplitPartition(numberPerBatch); //error here

    while (offset < LoopMax)
    {
        //do the index of partion here  PartitionMembers

        offset++;
    }
}
```

any suggest or example how to comsume those Method? this is really what i need partition to my List. When i tried consume that method i got error like this:

> List' does not contain a definition for 'SplitPartition' and no accessible extension method 'SplitPartition' accepting a first argument of type 'List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Oof, the performance of this could be terrible. Also, never post on SO saying "I got an error" without including the exact error message

Comment: @CaiusJard sorry i will add error message that i had, i will edit my question

Comment: Numberperbatch should be declared as int. Post your error message.

Comment: hi , that [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) (`SplitPartition`) is a [private](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/). where did you try to invoke it? is it in the same class?

Comment: @CaiusJard: Why do you say the performance could be "terrible"?  While you could get an easy performance boost by setting the `Capacity` of some of these lists, it's still O(n).

Comment: That's why I say it COULD be terrible. Doesn't even need the overhead of lists. Arrays would be fine because we know the numbers

Comment: Also, your method indicates it will return 5000 members and your batch size if half a million. How many chunks are you expecting? Seems like it will always be 1 if the assumption from the method name is true

Comment: Where is that extension method in comparison to `ExportToCsv`? Is it in another class? Is it in the same class?

Comment: @RoadRunner it is the same class... exactly both of that method are in the same class..why did method `SplitPartition` cannot be access from `ExportToCsv` method?

Comment: @CaiusJard it is not 5000 but 500000, `getDataTop5000();` just only name of method that will return 4millions of data. so 4millions devided by 500000 will get 8 chunk. This partition is veru useful when split of export csv file into several part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd be better off rolling your own solution to this. Say you had downloaded 5000 members and wanted to write them to file in 50 member chunks (100 files), you can simply do:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(10000);
int x= 0;
foreach(var m in members){
  if(++x%50 == 0){
    File.WriteAllText(sb.ToString(), $@"c:\temp\{x%50}.csv");
    sb.Length = 0;
  }
  sb.AppendLine(m.ToCsvRepresentationEtc());
}
```

The point I'm making is not about writing to file, it's about knowing what you want to do (eg write to file) with your chunks and making a single pass of the enumerable and the cutting into chunks being done in that pass by changing what action you take every now and then. In this example changing the action is a simple modulo, that empties the buffer of the StringBuilder and writes out to a filename based on the modulo. This is preferable to burning a boatload of memory (the performance of that split routine could well be horrific depending on the numbers involved; it makes no attempt to provision any suitably sized list based on the numbers) on pre-chunking it

At the very least consider rewriting the chunking so that it uses straight 2d (jaggy) arrays or pre-capacity-provisioned lists; you know what sizes they need to be from how big the passed in List is and the chunk size:

```
public static class ListExtensions{

  public List<List<T>> SplitPartition<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, int size)
  {
    var chunks = new List<List<T>>(collection.Count/size + 1);
    var temp = new List<T>(size);

    foreach (var element in collection)
    {
        if (temp.Count == size)
        {
            chunks.Add(temp);
            temp = new List<T>(size);
        }
        temp.Add(element);
    }
    chunks.Add(temp);

    return chunks;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggest answer but finally i change and move method `SplitPartition` to another static class. and it worked.

Comment: That's what the final bit of code in my answer does. It also simplified the method and uses maths to pre allocate the lists. The problem with a list if you don't size it when you create it is that it will resize when it runs out of space and by rescue I mean it allocated a new array internally that is twice the size of the old one and copies everything over. AFAICR it starts out at 16, so if you load 5000 items in it will resize at 16 32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096 and finally 8192 - 9 resizes and thousands of needless copy operations. If you know you want 5000, pre-size to 5000

Comment: PS just caught your comment that you're chunking into half a million rows at a time. Using an auto expanding list for that is pretty horrific. I think I'd go with my first advice to auto roll the csv file path on every half million records and stream them from the db to the file, writing line by line. It's minimal memory use. Using list for half a million records is 15 resizes and millions of unnecessary Copy operations

Comment: why i need `var chunks = new List<List<T>>(collection.Count/size + 1);` ? I already devided the collection with following this code `double LoopMax = Math.Ceiling(members.Count / (double)numberPerBatch);` explain me

Comment: i explained why in detail in the two comments above? List is not some magical thing that grows smoothly, it has an internal array of 16 and when it fills up it doubles but that means copying all the items from the 16 array to the 32 array. Then when 32 is full it doubles and copies again. And it keeps going doubling and copying and doubling and copying, and it's really slow and a huge waste of resources to keep doubling and copying, so when you KNOW you're gonna put 5000 items in the list you just use the command that preallocates an array of 5000.. no more doubling and copying

Comment: Same thing for the list that holds the lists; you know the size you'll need, so pre allocate it. Getting rid of loopmax isn't the only difference between your code and mine, but your splitpartition doesn't make use of your loopmax so I'm not sure why you think it does anything in terms of splitting. Most of your code outside SplitPartition seems redundant to be honest, and it's generally better to use foreach or work off the sizes of collections than work off ints that try to be the same as the size of the collection. Just say `collection.Count` rather than `numberPerBatch` if they both 500000

Comment: It is really clear explanation and given me more knowledges that can be performed my code faster. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Can't see your full code, but:

- extension methods need to belong to `static` classes, and
- this class and method need to be visible from the calling code.

In particular, I can see that your `ExportToCsv` is not static, so it doesn't belong to a static class, so I can deduce that your `private` extension method either:

- doesn't belong to a static class, or
- belongs to a separate class than your `ExportToCsv` method, and hence can't be seen from it

So make a `public static` class to hold the extension method, mark the method itself `public static`, and you should be in business.

More details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-implement-and-call-a-custom-extension-method

Comment: the problem is method cannot be access in the same class. excatly `SplitPartition` is in static method and `ExportToCsv ` consume. I moved into another static class and it solved